# Header height too big after uploading my logo

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm working on a Wordpress website and I use the custom CSS to change small things from the template. So I only know how to work with html and CSS.
But now I have a problem...

After uploading my logo, the header seems to stretch slightly out of proportion. There seems to be too much padding above the logo, more then below it, which makes it look uneven and the header just looks slightly too large on the whole. There is just too much white space in it… Whereas it was slimmer and a lot more streamline before uploading the logo.

The page I need help with: https://delizabeth.nl

Is there any way someone can help me fix this.

Comment: Also, your choice of white green text fails accessibility contrast. The green is too light and may be very difficult for some to read

Comment: Here is one way of testing your colors for readability: https://contrast-ratio.com/#%23B1DCB3-on-white

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your header has a `max-height` of `200px`.
With the image added the way it is, the actual content exceeds that height and is cut off at the bottom.

[image: Header exceeds max-height]

The logo has padding around it and margin at the bottom. Since it only has margin at the bottom, the text doesn´t get verticaly centered to where the center of the image is but to the middle including the margin.

[image: Logo padding and margin]

If you remove the padding and the margin around the logo, then the extra whitespace will disappear and only the padding from the header itself will remain.
It then all fits inside the max-height so nothing is cut off.

[image: result]

I don´t know how that theme works, but if it always has the same ID then the css would be:

```css
#media_image-11 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thx you so much!! it worked and your explanation is perfect, thx ! Can I maybe ask you one more question? :)

Comment: @Freddie Nice to hear. What´s your question?

Comment: Thx you are amazing! So everything on my website is responsive except my footer and i do not know how that happend and how to fix it. Do you have any idea?

Comment: And if ik go to the mobile design the dropdown-menu is not working very well and comes out under the hero-image.

Comment: @Freddie you have a hard set width for `.pre-footer .inner` set to `1400px`. Remove that and your footer should work.

Comment: @Freddie if you remove the `max-height` in your header completely, then your dropdown should work as well. But you maybe should adjust the width of your media-queries that hide it. Also the button is white on white background if you don´t hover over it (at least for me). Might want to fix that as well.

Comment: Thx you so much! The only thing is that if you go to the dropdown-menu for the mobile design the Menu-toggle in under the logo and I really want that on the right of the header do you know how to fix that? And the sub-menu is still under the hero-image if you know what I mean. Sorry for all the questions but you are helping me a lot!!!

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Freddie As I see you already fixed the position of the Menu-toggle button. But you still have a max-height on your `header` (in multiple css-classes even). Either remove all of them or if you can´t remove them, add `max-height: unset;` to a css-class that overrides all other classes.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set class[widget] (padding: initial;) and you can set image height and width.